# Flask-SQLAlchemy + create_all() failed on many-to-many relationship creation

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have following application structure:

```
run.py
|->app
   |->models
      |-> user.py (declares role-to-user relationship table and User model)
      |-> role.py (declares Role model)
   |-> main.py (contains initialization and all required imports)
   |-> extensions (here sqlalchemy variable declared to be imported later)
```

When I trying to create initial DB structure following way:

```
from app.models import *
from app.extensions import db
from app.main import myapp #app is initialized with all packages  like assets, db, security, etc.

with myapp.test_request_context():
    db.create_all()
```

I've got an exception:
NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'users_to_roles.user_id' could not find table 'users' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

I also tried to dow it following way:

```
@app.before_first_request
def initialize_database():
    db.create_all()
```

with no success

I tried to move `Role` to the same file where `User` model is declared with the same result. I read the docs here: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html but it says 'you just need to import `db`' and it does not works.

Here is how `User` model and relationship table are declared (Role model looks similar to `User`):

```
users_to_roles_association_table = db.Table('users_to_roles',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id')))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    .......
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=users_to_roles_association_table,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

How to create initial DB structure using Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the features of `Flask-SQLAlchemy` is automatic table name generation from the class name when the `__tablename__` class attribute isn't defined for a model class. From https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html:

> Some parts that are required in SQLAlchemy are optional in
>   Flask-SQLAlchemy. For instance the table name is automatically set for
>   you unless overridden. It’s derived from the class name converted to
>   lowercase and with “CamelCase” converted to “camel_case”.

In your case, the `User` class will have it's `__tablename__` attribute inferred as `user` which means there is no `users` table defined.

You can fix this by either explicitly setting `__tablename__` or by changing the `ForeignKey` parameters to match the autogenerated table names:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    ...

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    ...
```

or leave the `__tablename__` attribute undefined and modify the association table:

```py
users_to_roles_association_table = db.Table('users_to_roles',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id')))
```

Comment: I tried to override __tablename__ by explicitly setting table name, but it still follows the default singular name.

Comment: @KevinQ Do you sample code you can share that demonstrates the issue?